# Inconsistent newlines placed in contentEditable after pasting from other html

Tags: html, contenteditable

Given this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zax0gsv7/1/

```
Copy this:<br><br>

<div style="width:200px; border:1px solid black; overflow:scroll; height:50px; white-space:nowrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam faucibus, nunc sed mollis luctus, ex nisi fringilla mauris, a tincidunt metus est sit amet justo. Aliquam semper elementum ullamcorper. Cras tincidunt facilisis ligula, vitae pulvinar dui fringilla quis. Proin posuere laoreet enim, quis laoreet libero suscipit vitae. Vestibulum vulputate massa ex, in imperdiet nunc consectetur vel.
Nulla justo sapien, viverra ut tristique a, euismod at diam. Integer convallis felis ut dictum interdum. Curabitur finibus sollicitudin metus, nec varius arcu mollis vitae. Sed fringilla congue purus non faucibus. Pellentesque venenatis mauris sodales, ultrices orci eu, vehicula odio. Suspendisse sed volutpat magna. Maecenas lorem purus, efficitur in varius vel, consectetur non tortor. Nulla facilisi. Praesent a est id nisi egestas bibendum sed a odio. Nam in nibh eu mauris egestas eleifend sit amet quis enim. Phasellus blandit eleifend ligula. </div>

<br>here:<br><br>

<pre id="box" style="border:1px solid black; width:100%; min-height:100px;max-height:100px; overflow:scroll;" contenteditable="true">
</pre>

<br>then click here:<br><br>

<button id="set">Number of newlines:</button> <span id="out"></span>
```

in firefox when manually copying-pasting the content of the first box into the second box which is contentEditable, some newlines are being added that weren't there in the first box. There is only one newline that I added to the original which is before "Nulla justo sapien", which gets preserved.
Apparently on chrome no newlines are added but also the manually added newline gets removed. Also added a small function that counts the newlines.

Would like to know if this is a bug or expected behavior and how to workaround it on firefox and chrome to correctly preserve the original newlines without adding other newlines in the process.

Answer (score 0):

**In short**

This is not a bug. This is a different way of internal HTML handling by different browsers.

**Long description**

The good thing of `contenteditable` is that it allows you to change the text which is inside of your block. This really works in every browser, you can copy even a markup and styles.

The bad thing and the biggest problem of `contenteditable` is that the HTML which is generated in a shadow for the `contenteditable` is different in different browsers. Please feel the difference here between the `input` / `textarea` and `contenteditable`: when in standard inputs you have a property called `value` which stores the real value, in `contenteditable` you have HTML, a markup language which skips the spaces / newlines.

And finally, here it comes: there is a [contenteditable standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/editing.html) which is not very descriptive. It does say how it should behave, however although according to the standard new line should generate `<br>` different browsers handle even that case differently. E.g. current version of Chrome wraps the line inside of `<div>` instead. Even the standard is not respected as you may see from this example.

Your case is not even in the standard. Every browser implementation is different. And your case is not a bug: newlines in HTML code mean nothing -> you can still edit the content and the HTML looks the same even with 1000 newlines.

A conclusion I've made for myself when I was trying `contenteditable` - this is so inconsistent that I won't ever use it. And it works so far.